# How to read this xpath expression?

Tags: xml, xpath

Can someone explain me please how to read this expression in xpath:
`/a/b[3]/preceding-sibling::*[1]/d/@id` ?
(My problem is mainly to understand this part: `preceding-sibling::*[1]`)

In given the following xml document:

```
<a>
      <b> 
            <c ref="a5">2000</c>
            <d id="a3">3</d>
            <d id="a4">4</d> 
            <d id="a5">a</d> 
            <d id="a6">b</d>
             <f></f> 
      </b> 

      <b> 
            <c ref="a5">3000</c> 
            <f></f> 
            <d id="a7">7</d> 
            <d id="a8">8</d> 
            <d id="a9">9</d> 
      </b>

      <b> 
            <c ref="a6">4000</c>
             <f></f> 
      </b> 
</a>
```

Why it returns the following output:

```
Attribute='id=a7'
Attribute='id=a8'
Attribute='id=a9'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make a lot of sense in the context of your sample xml, but it means this:

```
/a/b[3]
```

find the third `<b>` child of `<a>` - the last `<b>` in this case.

```
/preceding-sibling::*[1]
```

find the child of `<a>` immediately (first) preceding that `<b>` child, regardless of its name. In this case, this (2nd) child also happens to be a `<b>`, so it's equivalent to `/a/b[2]`, but whatever.

```
/d
```

find the `<d>` children of that `<b>` - there are 3 of them in the 2nd `<b>`. Finally,

```
/@id
```

Find the attribute value of the attribute `id` of these 3 children - and that's how you get your output.

Comment: So this part `/preceding-sibling::*[1]` returns the first brother before the context ? I thought that this part returns the first brother from all the preceding brothers.

Comment: @JobProcessTask First brother - or, as it's called in the xml inner circles - first sibling...

Comment: @JackFleeting My confusion was that I thought that it returns the first brother in the other direction, namely the first child of `a`..

Comment: @JobProcessTask Oh, I see what you mean: no, you count backward, as it were, from the context child, toward the first child. In the case of the reverse `following-sibling` you start from the same context child and go forward toward the last child.

Comment: @JackFleeting So always the "count" starting from the context?

Comment: @JobProcessTask Indeed.